# Chain methods only if needed

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
  spark = SparkSession.builder \
       .appName("sss")\
       .master("spark://" + os.environ["MASTER_HOST"] + ":7077")\
       .config("spark.submit.deployMode", os.environ["DEPLOY_MODE"])\
       .getOrCreate()
```

How can I configure the code, so that it only chains specific parts of the code if conditions are true: Here's an imaginary code:

```
  spark = SparkSession.builder \
       .appName("sss")\
       .master("spark://" + os.environ["MASTER_HOST"] + ":7077")\ if os.environ["MASTER_HOST"]
       .config("spark.submit.deployMode", os.environ["DEPLOY_MODE"])\ if os.environ["DEPLOY_MODE"]
       .getOrCreate()
```

I think this will work, but this code seems to long for me:

```
  spark = SparkSession.builder \
       .appName("sss")\
  if os.environ["MASTER_HOST"]: 
     spark =  spark.master("spark://" + os.environ["MASTER_HOST"] + ":7077")
   ....
```

What's the smallest code snippet you can think of to produce the desired results?

Comment: Yes, do that "will work" code. Don't get too fancy. Depending on how the object behaves you can probably omit the `spark =`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best you can do.

```
builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("sss")
if os.environ["MASTER_HOST"]:
       builder = builder.master("spark://" + os.environ["MASTER_HOST"] + ":7077")
if os.environ["DEPLOY_MODE"]:
       builder = builder.config("spark.submit.deployMode", os.environ["DEPLOY_MODE"])
spark = builder.getOrCreate()
```

Or

```
master_host = os.environ["MASTER_HOST"]
deploy_mode = os.environ["DEPLOY_MODE"]
builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("sss")
if master_host:
       builder = builder.master("spark://" + master_host + ":7077")
if deploy_mode:
       builder = builder.config("spark.submit.deployMode", deploy_mode)
spark = builder.getOrCreate()
```